# Get a text container with max-content to hug text closely if line breaking happens to cause it to take up less than max-content?

Tags: html, css

Imagine an element containing only text:

```html
<p>
  Foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar
</p>
```

I want the node to take up no more than, say, 100px in width. This is trivial to achieve with `max-width: 100px`:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

However, I also want the container to hug the text closely - to take up the minimum amount of horizontal space required. With only `max-width` specified, if the line breaks fall in a specific position, the container will still take up `max-width` amount of space, even though it could be even narrower to fit the text:

[image: A text container with max-width taking up more than strictly required to fit the text]

I tried using a combination of `fit-content`, `max-content`, `min-content` with `min-width`, `max-width` and `width`, but none of them really achieve what I want.

When adding `min-content`, the container will hug the text closely, but that would also require me to add a `min-width` to make sure the there aren't line breaks on every single line.

The problem with adding a `min-width` is I can't know upfront what the smallest content in the container could be – if it's just a single word `OK`, I only want it to take up as much space as needed to hug that word. So a `min-width` of, say, `50ch` would break this behavior.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/elisehein/pen/ZErwoOo)

Comment: I think the reason is that the div can't hold three 'Foobarbaz', you can add `font-size: 15px;` and see the result. Or I misunderstand something :)

Comment: So essentially, you want to base the computed width on the number and length of the words in the content. I believe this isn't possible with just CSS.